# Proving converse of Ceva's theorem or if the opposite angles of a quadrilateral is $ 180^{\circ}$ is cyclic without the method of contradiction

Tags: geometry, logic

So far whatever proofs I have encountered  for proving the converse of Cevas theorem and the  if the opposite angles of a  quadrilateral is $ 180^{\circ}$  then it is cyclic, it is by the method of contradiction that is assuming the opposite of what we want to show and then arriving at a contradiction. Is there any direct or constructive proof for these statements without assuming the negation?

Comment: What is the connection between the two? You have two questions?

Comment: In Euclidean geometry,I have observed that some of the proofs are proved by the method of contradiction and these two proofs fall in this category and are more elementary , so I have been thinking if there is any direct proof for these two.

Comment: Is this good? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ceva%27s_theorem

Comment: What do you mean by "cyclic"? Inscribed in a circle?

Comment: Yes; inscribed in a circle